# nginx redirect с http на https с условием

Tags: nginx, ssl

Мне нужно сделать редирект с http на https для всех страниц сайта кроме тех которые находятся в site.com/admin/**

```
server {
 ....
if ($request_uri ~ "^(.*)admin(.*)") {
 return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
}

listen 145.14.157.58:80;
```

}

Comment: Что мешает сделать https и для страниц admin тоже?

Comment: забудьте об `if` вообще. сделайте через `location`

Comment: Я в nginx нуб, недавно на web перешел. Можете пример показать как это реализовать

Comment: Т.е. вы не хотите переводить на https ровно те страницы которые по логике должны быть первыми в кандидаты на https.